# Android Apache Commons Email Class SimpleMail not found

Tags: android, email, classnotfoundexception, apache-commons

I want to send an email using the apache commons email, that make it easy, or should make it. All the classes are included, but this error appears.

Here is my code and the logcat.

```
email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
email.setSmtpPort(465);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("myemail@gmail.com", "mypass"));
try {
    email.setFrom("mymail@gmail.com");
    email.setSubject("TestMail");
    email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
    email.addTo("dest@hotmail.com");
    email.send();
} catch (EmailException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

OBS: email was declares defore as:

```
Email email;
```

The stack trace:

```
10-15 10:36:57.254 1755-1755/contasts.jao.email E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: contasts.jao.email, PID: 1755
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/mail/SimpleEmail;
        at contasts.jao.email.MainActivity.mandarEmail(MainActivity.java:54)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_d240637ab16909631b8e0522acd22a25d9696630-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.4.0_af59f0bca6bcee7449190085fe52534aee83e2f1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-23.4.0_bd8c75447dc30c698da5700ab2e0aefa2fe4fe35-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.4.0_3f1746aab7883e4aa141bfb0b148adeead28e570-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-23.4.0_f3af541e04a191f70d73c09b1b309272e4406a2b-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/contasts.jao.email/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-animated-vector-drawable-23.4.0_241ea31a1f8c1e8e0741e2b1a365cddd6e9449c2-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/contasts.jao.email-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at contasts.jao.email.MainActivity.mandarEmail(MainActivity.java:54)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/contasts.jao.email-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/contasts.jao.email-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:5
```

I've declared and imported the class.

Comment: Provide your build.gradle file. How have you set dependency to apache commons?

Answer (score 0):

Please Change The HostName

```
email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
```

to

```
email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
```